# How to define only last test method assertion will be involved

Tags: junit

I have a two class's for testing regression test. We have in some case more than one test method in the class and in the methods we are usually using assertions. I want to know if there any method is available, to make use `@Rule` test method only the last method in the class. Here is my code:

```
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
public class JustOneClass extends ParentClass {

    @Rule
    public class GeneralRule articleHotspotRule = new class GeneralRule (this);

    @Test
    aMethod(){
        Assert.assertTrue()
    }
    @Test
    bMethod(){
        Assert.assertTrue()
    }
    @Test
    cMethod(){
        Assert.assertTrue()
    }
    @Test
    dMethod(){
        if this assert is failed Assert.assertTrue()
    }
}
```

We have a another class which extends `TestWatcher`

```
public class GeneralRule extends TestWatcher {

    private ParentClass baseTest;

    public GeneralRule (final GeneralRule generalRule) {
        this.baseTest = generalRule;
    }

    @Override
    protected void failed(final Throwable e, final Description description) {
        baseTest.after();
    }

}
```

in this case I want that `baseTest.after()` will be used only if assertion of `dMedthod` is failed.

Comment: You want to create a rule that executes a method of the TestClass only if the last test method of TestClass failed? Is that it?

Comment: It might help to explain the problem you're trying to solve instead, this seems really bizarre

Comment: I just want to executes a mathod base.after() only in one condition en that is if the  the assert method is failed(Marked up in de dMethod()).

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using a rule to try and check for the failure, how about checking for the failure condition and then fail the test programatically? Certainly not as elegant or reusable as a rule but may satisfy your requirement.

```
@Test
public void dMethod() {
    ...
    if(actual == false) {             // check for failure scenario
        after();                      // call the after method
        Assert.fail("hello failure"); // programatically fail the test
    }
}
```